# How can I use the "frog jump" forward of Gael's Greatsword on PC?

Tags: dark-souls-3

Gael's Great Sword has two attacks:

1) Weapon Art + light attack (Left button of mouse) = The rolling attack

2) Weapon art + heavy attack (shift + left button of mouse) = The Frog Jump

The problem with the normal Frog Jump is, you move back first, then strike forward.

However, I have seen in some Youtube videos specially PvPSkillz that he uses the frog jump as a gap closer, I think he uses Xbox, so I'm thinking, How can I change the direction of the Frog Jump? A typical frog jump moves backwards first, then forward, PvPSkillz frog jump is forward, forward!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just successfully tested it, here is [my short video](https://youtu.be/qcPKwwDzq0E). I did it on PC with keyboard and mouse.

How I did it (with all defaults key bindings):

1. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> all the time.
2. Right mouse click to make first jump.
3. Now simultaneously press backwards move (<kbd>S</kbd>) and click left mouse to do forward frog jump.
4. During jump press forward (<kbd>W</kbd>) and then right mouse to attack.

The problem is, that this does not work if you locked your target: when target is locked instead of turning around backwards move will trigger step back. So you need either do entire thing without locking or release target after step 2 and hold target again after step 3. Looks like it will require a lot of practice to perfect this move.

Comment: A LOT of training but IT WORKS! Thank you!